# Old javascript files are being compiled into the var/clientlibs directory

Tags: aem

I just recently updated some javascript files in a CQ5.6 instance. I deleted the vars/clientlibs folder so that CQ would regenerate the appropriate files on next page load. When it regenerated them it still included the original javascript. I double checked and both the authoring and publishing instances had the new javascript so I do not know where it is holding onto the old stuff.

So, where does CQ cache the files that it generates its var files from?

Answer (score 4):

CQs clientlibs are cached by the [HtmlLibraryManager](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/widget/HtmlLibraryManager.html). Use jad, JDecompiler to see it's implementation.

One workaround I found is to rename the node of the clientlib. So if it is myClientLib, just rename it to myClientLib_somethingelse, then it will use the new js (It cleans HtmlLibraryManager's cache for the clientlib). After then you can rename it back.

**Update:**

I forgot to mention an url where you can rebuild the clientlibs and here you can also invalidate the cache: `/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.rebuild.html`. It sometimes fails, but maybe it will work. :D

It is also an useful url for checking clientlibs: `/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.html`

Answer (score 2):

After deleting the /var/clientlibs cache you may also want to try restarting the `Adobe Granite UI Commons (com.day.cq.cq-widgets)` bundle from the `/system/console/bundles` view.

That bundle provides the `com.day.cq.widget.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl` service, which is responsible for compiling the clientlibs and could theoretically hold some in-memory cache as well.

At one point this was definitely true for the JSP compiler, where removing the /var/classes/org/apache/jsp folder was not enough to force a recompile without also restarting the JSP scripting support bundle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic problem, and it will be worst when CSS/JS got cached on client browser. I would recommend to use ACS Commons, Versioned Clientlibs feature in your site to add version number in css/js files. Please refer: http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/versioned-clientlibs.html